# java - keep painted rectangle inside JPanel bounds when user paints

Tags: java, swing, rect

im developing an image processing program. I really want a little help in this issue and i hope to find a solution.

My problem is. Im enabling the user to draw rectangle when the mouse clicked and dragged on an image inside JPanel, when the user moves out the JPanel bounds the rectangle still painted some of it inside the half thing is out... got it?

ok .. the painted rectangle, it's actually outside the the bounds of the JPanel that contains the image, it doesnt keep itself inside the bounds, so when user drag the mouse out i want to keep it inside never goes out because this will give an empty X and Y, and will gives you and exception RasterFormatException, x lies outside the raster !! 
can anyone help my to control the painted rectangle?

thanks in advance ..

Comment: *"got it?"*  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3):

In your MouseMotionListener, mouseDragged method, check to see if the mouse's Point is outside of the bounds of your JPanel, and then respond accordingly if it is.

```
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
  Dimension d = getSize();
  Point p = me.getPoint();
  if (p.x > d.x || p.x < 0 || p.y > d.y ||d.y < 0) {
    // set drawing parameters to zero
    repaint();
    return;
  }

  // other mouse drawing code
}
```